# Complexity of iteration through std::set

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set

I know that time complexity of iterating throught whole set takes `O(n)` time, where `n` is size of set. 
The question is, what is complexity of iterating between two iterators, `itBegin` and `itEnd`? Maybe it's something like `O(itEnd - itBegin + log n)`, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Still O(n), with n being the distance between the iterators. I'd recommend that you reread the definition of asymptotic complexity.

Comment: I think you're wrong. For example, if `itEnd = itBegin + 1` then complexity will be `O(log n)` but not `O(1)`.

Comment: *"For example, if itEnd = itBegin + 1 then complexity will be O(log n) but not O(1)"* - you can't deduce big-O complexity from the n=1 case alone... it's about how required computation changes as n approaches infinity.

Comment: It's not a case where `n=1`. `itBegin` is not `s.begin()` and `itEnd` is not `s.end()`

Comment: Ok... taking a step back, *"Maybe it's something like O(itEnd - itBegin + log n), but I can't prove it."* - no - it's simply `O(itEnd - itBegin)`.  If you know `itEnd - itBegin` is on average linearly related to `n`, you could simplify that to O(n).  What MikeMB said was "O(n), with n being the distance between the iterators" - i.e. `itEnd - itBegin`.  For your counter-example of `itEnd = itBegin + 1` - in C++ adding 1 to an iterator means the next element: they're 1 apart and using MikeMB's definition of `n` as the "distance between the iterators", it's indeed the n=1 case as I said.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithmic complexity of iterating whole `std::set` is O(n). But time consumption is bigger than iterating `std::vector` since vector uses single memory block.

If you want to iterate between 2 iterators `itBegin` and `itEnd` it will be O(n1) too, but `n1` will be something like `std::distance(itEnd, itBegin)`, which is less than `n` in first case. This is the case when you have iterator already.

If you want to find those positions by value before iterating (you have no iterators at the begining) - this becomes `O(log n) + O(n2)` which is actually `O(log n)`. Say, if you want to iterate from value `123` to the end - this will be `O(log n)` to find iterator to `123` and `O(n2)` to iterate.

Comment: "`O(log n) + O(n)` which is actually `O(log n)`" - it'd be clearer using different letters for your set size and distance (I'll use *n* and *d*), but the assertion's wrong anyway: say `itBegin` is `begin()` and `itEnd()` is `end()` - O(d) dominates O(log n), whereas for nearby `itBegin`/`itEnd` the O(log n) dominates: unless there's reason to think the iterators will consistently be close, O(n) is a more meaningful overall assessment.

Comment: @TonyD i think your assertion is wrong in this part: "say itBegin is begin() and itEnd() is end() - O(d) dominates O(log n)". To get begin() and end() `std::set` wont search anything, so they are O(1). Then, iterating between them is something like `for(; itBegin!=itEnd; ++itBegin)`, which is O(n). So its overall O(n).

Comment: you're missing where I said I would use *d* to refer to the distance between the iterators in the set... in the case of begin->end, *d* == *n*, so *"O(d) dominates O(log n)"* is agreeing with your analysis that it is O(n) overall.  And given you agree on O(n), how about updating your answer?  Regarding O(1) vs O(log n) - what you've said is true of begin and end if you're starting with the iterators, but just search for an element by value that's at or near those extremes and it'll be the more general O(log n) case.

Comment: @TonyD edited post to clearify different sizes of `n`. But, i should mention in terms of algorithmic complexity its no difference between O(n1) and O(n) since its talking about complexity, not wallclock time consumption.

Comment: *"no difference between O(n1) and O(n)"* - that depends on whether the specific problem being solved constrains *n1* more.   For example, if you had an arbitrarily large *n*, but the task was searching for a value and taking up to 100 values either side to form an average, it would be dominated by O(log n) for getting the iterators, with the constant-number-of-nodes iterations being O(1) and ignored.  All up, I believe a correct answer should read something like "becomes whichever's worse of `O(log n)` and `O(n1)`", with worst case O(n).  Separately, not sure where *n2* came from...?

Answer (score -2):

The complexity will be o(n) (little o of n) and not O(n) that means in worst case you will iterate through the whole set .